# Windows xp: I want chkdsk to run at every boot

Tags: windows-xp, boot, chkdsk

I've seen different question about how to stop this behaviour but I really want it to happen.
I have a videopoker machine that gets turned off brutally from an external power button so often I can get disk problems.
I would like chkdsk /r to run at EVERY boot before windows...

Any ways to achieve this?

Comment: There's no point if you formatted it as NTFS. Chkdsk checks for errors and is really only useful on FAT filesystems because NTFS keeps track of everything it writes before it writes it (called journaling) to keep track of any errors that may come up and fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the C:\ drive to be checked at next boot by using [`chkntfs.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160963):

```
chkntfs /c c:
```

To automate this, you can put that line in a file called "ForceChkDsk.bat" and add those to the [Startup](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/hwandprograms/autorun.mspx) folder. Then whenever the machine starts up, it will add the disk to the `Boot Execute` registry entry and have the OS check it the next time it is restarted.

Comment: I think this requires command line confirmation...

Comment: @BloodPhilia: I just ran `chkntfs /c c:` in a prompt and it did not. (I know that `chkdsk` would, but this is different.) A further `chkntfs c:` says that it has been scheduled on the next startup.

Comment: @yhw42 Oh, do excuse me, I read "`chkdsk`" instead of "`chkntfs`".

Comment: @BloodPhilia: no worries. I had some chkdsk issues a while back and found [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218461) that tries to explain things... I had to read it several times. `:)`

Comment: Also:

fsutil dirty set c: